# C# Object manipulation in method

Tags: c#, object, reference

I am having trouble understanding how object manipulation is working in C# methods. I know that when you pass an object to a method, a reference to that object is passed. With that in mind, I figured that option 1 would work like this:

1. The root variable comes into the method as a reference to root
2. When you set it to root.left it would update that reference to the left of root
3. Then when you set it to a new node, root would now have a member in it's left field.

However, only option 2 works. Why is that?

Please ignore that it is static if you can, this is merely an example I made to learn how this works. I tried making it not static without using any member variables and it did the same thing.

```
class binaryTreeNode 
{
    public binaryTreeNode left;
    public binaryTreeNode right;
    public int data;
    private binaryTreeNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public binaryTreeNode() {}


    public static void insert(binaryTreeNode root, int data) 
    {
        binaryTreeNode newNode = new binaryTreeNode(data);
        
        //option 1
        root = root.left;
        root = newNode;

        //option 2
        root.left = newNode;

        // in main():
        // binaryTreeNode root = new binaryTreeNode();
        // root.data = 5;
        // binaryTreeNode.insert(root, 3);
        // Console.WriteLine(root.left.data);
        // null reference on option 1
        // outputs properly (int data) on option 2
    }
}
```

Comment: In C# class and method names should be in Pascal-case, not camel-case.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. You can check it out and if it makes sense, you should be confident regarding references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your third step wrong. Whenever you use `=` you simply assign the right hand side reference to whatever variable is on the left hand side of the sign. With that in mind you simply change the reference for `root` from `root.left` to `newNode` but `root.left` would stay unchanged. Therefore the previous line is useless and option 2 is the way to go.

Let's look at some examples to get your way of thinking with references right.

First, let's create a very simple class:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Value;

    public Model(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Now let's look at some examples:

> Example 1:

```
var model = new Model(3);
```

Creates a `Model` instance with value `3` and assigns it to the variable named `model`.

```
var reference = model;
```

Assigns the instance saved in `model` to `reference`. They now both point to the same instance.

```
reference.Value = 2;
```

Changes the `Value` property of the instance to `2`.

```
Console.WriteLine(model.Value);
```

Outputs `2`, since the variables `reference` and `model` were pointing to the same instance.

> Example 2

```
var model = new Model(3);
```

Creates a `Model` instance with value `3` and assigns it to the variable named `model`.

```
var model2 = new Model(4);
```

Creates another `Model` instance with value `4` and assigns it to the variable named `model2`.

```
var reference = model;
```

Assigns the first instance saved in `model` to `reference`. They now both point to the same instance.

```
reference = model2;
```

Assigns the second instance saved in `model2` to `reference`. Therefore variable `model` and `reference` now **do not point** at the same instance anymore.

```
reference.Value = 2;
```

Changes the `Value` property of the second instance to `2`. The `Value` property's value of the first instance therefore remains unchanged and continues to be `3`.

```
Console.WriteLine(model.Value);
```

Outputs `3`.

```
Console.WriteLine(model2.Value);
```

Outputs `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the good, clear answer! So if I am understanding correctly, any object that is passed to a method is passed as a pointer of that type essentially. Using assignment `=` just changes where the pointer is pointing. 

In C++ you could use the `*` operator to de-reference the pointer, and then you can actually change the value that is being pointed at. Is there any way to do this in C# and/or is my thought process wrong?

Comment: "Using assignment = just changes where the pointer is pointing": Exactly.

Comment: You can work in C# with pointers too, but that is not recommended and you have to do that in an "unsafe" block. I've never done it before so I can't help you much there but there should be enough information around on how to do that. However, generally you shouldn't do that. If you want to change where a variable is pointing at you simply reassign it to a reference that points to the instance in question. My exmaple should help you with understanding that.

Comment: Another very important thing to keep in mind is that only class instances are references. If a value type (like int, bool or any struct) is assigned to a variable through = then that value on the right hand side is passed to the variable but both of them stand for their own and don't reference the same value. If you copy either of the examples I posted and change the Model class to a struct, you will notice how the output will not have changed since the variable does point at a different (new copied) instance.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference and all the examples! People like you help out so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms for the option one - think about reference as a separate pointer object by itself - this object points to an actual instance of something that you are passing to your method.
So, inside your method, you are assigning an object "root.left" to this reference "object", therefore this reference object now points to the ’root.left’ instance.
then again, another assignment - again, root reference points to the ’newNode’ instance. But the actual thing, the original root object, to which the reference was passed inside the method has not been modified.
Only the reference  has been modified and it is now pointing to something else.

Option 2 actually changes something inside the object, which the passed reference is pointing to - therefore the original actual root object is modified.

This is a bit of a simplification, but at least should point you in the right direction.